# Extending Right Edge Boundary Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit

I'm working on a game and have a question about edge boundaries. For making a game that is contained within the window if the iPhone I can do this:

```
- (void) createSceneContents
{
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor blackColor];
    self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
}
```

The only other method that looked appealing is

```
 bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:ToPoint
```

I was able to set a leftmost boundary with this method and set a floor and walk left and right with my character. However, the character will fall off the world once it reaches the edge. What I'm going for is an extended background essentially that will be off the screen but ultimately has a far right edge upon which a player can't proceed further. The camera will follow the player as they go either to the left or right edge. The background will most likely consist of different images that will be loaded in once the user reaches the edge of a background. If anyone has tips or advice I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: instead of self.frame use a custom cgrect with the desired coordinates and size for the boundary

Comment: Thnak you that worked perfectly.